# "Expression is either incorrect or too complex"

Tags: sql, ms-access

I believe I'm in need of learning how to write the following code more elegantly. The issue is that I'm working with a bunch of tables (Wasn't me who created these or I would have simplified it down to one.) & I'm needing to query information against all of them at once. I'm working with MS Access and this is what my SQL statement looks like at the moment:

```
SELECT [Date (mm-dd-yy)], [Operator], [Operator Number], [Product Part Number], [Feet Produced], [Run Time], [Feet Produced]/[Run Time] AS [AVG Prod]
From [tblReports_16Braiding]
WHERE ((([Product Part Number])=[Forms]![AdminProdForm].[PartNumber]) AND [Date (mm-dd-yy)] Between [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[StartDate] And [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[EndDate]);
    Union
    SELECT [Date (mm-dd-yy)], [Operator], [Operator Number], [Product Part Number], [Feet Produced], [Run Time], [Feet Produced]/[Run Time] AS [AVG Prod]
From  [tblReports_24Braiding]
WHERE ((([Product Part Number])=[Forms]![AdminProdForm].[PartNumber]) AND [Date (mm-dd-yy)] Between [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[StartDate] And [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[EndDate]);
    Union
SELECT [Date (mm-dd-yy)], [Operator], [Operator Number], [Product Part Number], [Feet Produced], [Run Time], [Feet Produced]/[Run Time] AS [AVG Prod]
From [tblReports_Cabling]
WHERE ((([Product Part Number])=[Forms]![AdminProdForm].[PartNumber]) AND [Date (mm-dd-yy)] Between [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[StartDate] And [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[EndDate]);
Union
SELECT [Date (mm-dd-yy)], [Operator], [Operator Number], [Product Part Number], [Feet Produced], [Run Time], [Feet Produced]/[Run Time] AS [AVG Prod]
 From [tblReports_CompChain]
WHERE ((([Product Part Number])=[Forms]![AdminProdForm].[PartNumber]) AND [Date (mm-dd-yy)] Between [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[StartDate] And [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[EndDate]);
Union
SELECT [Date (mm-dd-yy)], [Operator], [Operator Number], [Product Part Number], [Feet Produced], [Run Time], [Feet Produced]/[Run Time] AS [AVG Prod]
From [tblReports_Jacketing]
WHERE ((([Product Part Number])=[Forms]![AdminProdForm].[PartNumber]) AND [Date (mm-dd-yy)] Between [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[StartDate] And [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[EndDate]);
Union
SELECT [Date (mm-dd-yy)], [Operator], [Operator Number], [Product Part Number], [Feet Produced], [Run Time], [Feet Produced]/[Run Time] AS [AVG Prod]
From [tblReports_Primary]
WHERE ((([Product Part Number])=[Forms]![AdminProdForm].[PartNumber]) AND [Date (mm-dd-yy)] Between [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[StartDate] And [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[EndDate]);
Union
SELECT [Date (mm-dd-yy)], [Operator], [Operator Number], [Product Part Number], [Feet Produced], [Run Time], [Feet Produced]/[Run Time] AS [AVG Prod]
From [tblReports_Printing]
WHERE ((([Product Part Number])=[Forms]![AdminProdForm].[PartNumber]) AND [Date (mm-dd-yy)] Between [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[StartDate] And [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[EndDate]);
Union
SELECT [Date (mm-dd-yy)], [Operator], [Operator Number], [Product Part Number], [Feet Produced], [Run Time], [Feet Produced]/[Run Time] AS [AVG Prod]
From [tblReports_Respool]
WHERE ((([Product Part Number])=[Forms]![AdminProdForm].[PartNumber]) AND [Date (mm-dd-yy)] Between [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[StartDate] And [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[EndDate]);
UNION SELECT [Date (mm-dd-yy)], [Operator], [Operator Number], [Product Part Number], [Feet Produced], [Run Time], [Feet Produced]/[Run Time] AS [AVG Prod]
 From [tblReports_Stranding]
WHERE ((([Product Part Number])=[Forms]![AdminProdForm].[PartNumber]) AND [Date (mm-dd-yy)] Between [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[StartDate] And [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[EndDate]);
```

In short, I'm just trying to union together a ton of tables. All with the same fields, create a new field from a simple division of two other fields, and then query against the unioned table with a form. Whenever I run this right now, I get an error that my SQL is wrong or too complex. I'm guessing too complex as I'm working with over 20,000 records across the nine tables.

Edit~~~

Upon removing the operation Expression on my largest table, about 8000 entries, the code works fine. Taking out this operation:

```
[Feet Produced]/[Run Time] AS [AVG Prod]
    From  [tblReports_24Braiding]
```

I need this field however in my query. I'm unable to do this in the table itself, because it's a linked table and therefore I can't save changes to it.

Comment: Im left wondering if access would handle thos better as select * from (select fields from table union select fields from table2 union etc...) Where conditions.  Do one select statement to union all the tables without filterd, then apply where filters to that massive union.   It seems a bit counter intuitive though, but ive had luck in the past with this approach

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly declare the parameters to free Access from guessing:

```
PARAMETERS
    [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[PartNumber]) Long,
    [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[StartDate] DateTime,
    [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[EndDate] DateTime;

SELECT 
    [Date (mm-dd-yy)], [Operator], [Operator Number], [Product Part Number], [Feet Produced], [Run Time], [Feet Produced]/[Run Time] AS [AVG Prod]
FROM 
    [tblReports_16Braiding]
WHERE 
    ((([Product Part Number])=[Forms]![AdminProdForm].[PartNumber]) AND [Date (mm-dd-yy)] Between [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[StartDate] And [Forms]![AdminProdForm].[EndDate]);

UNION ALL

SELECT ...  <snip>
```

Comment: I added the parameters, still no luck. Whenever I remove the operation expression on the largest table (8000 entries), the code works fine. [Feet Produced]/[Run Time] AS [AVG Prod] on my tblReports_24Braiding

Comment: Check that table for nasty values or Nulls in those fields. And/or: Will that query run on its own?

Comment: There aren't any null values - and yeah! The query will run on its own. It's just whenever I combine it to the rest of the SQL statement that there's the too complex error

Comment: Then try to split the query in two. If these run, then use a third query to union those two queries.