# MS ACCESS: Query Too Complex?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
SELECT [serial number], [page count], [minutes], [status], [activity], [venue short name], [assigned to], [publishing format name], [query], [photo], [notes], [tabular], [partpub], [statusdate]
FROM MyProd
WHERE ((MyProd.[Status] = [Forms]![My Prod]![StatusFilter]) 
        OR ([Forms]![My Prod]![StatusFilter] Is Null))
AND ((myprod.[activity] = [Forms]![My Prod]![ActivityFilter]) 
        OR ([Forms]![My Prod]![ActivityFilter] Is Null))
AND ((myprod.[activity] = [Forms]![My Prod]![ActivityFilter]) 
        OR ([Forms]![My Prod]![ActivityFilter] Is Null))
AND ((myprod.[venue short name] Like "*" & [Forms]![my prod]![venuefilter] & "*") 
        OR ([Forms]![my prod]![venuefilter] Is Null))
AND ((myprod.[assigned to] = [Forms]![My Prod]![ParticipantFilter]) 
        OR ([Forms]![My Prod]![ParticipantFilter] Is Null))
AND ((myprod.[publishing format name] = [Forms]![My Prod]![PubFilter]) 
        OR ([Forms]![My Prod]![PubFilter] Is Null))
AND ((myprod.[query] = [Forms]![My Prod]![PubFilter]) 
        OR ([Forms]![My Prod]![PubFilter] Is Null))
AND (iif([Forms]![My Prod]![SpecialRequestFilter]="Photo", MyProd.[Photo] Like -1, ([Forms]![My Prod]![PubFilter] Is Null)))
AND (iif([Forms]![My Prod]![SpecialRequestFilter]="Query", MyProd.[Query] Like -1, ([Forms]![My Prod]![PubFilter] Is Null)))
AND (iif([Forms]![My Prod]![SpecialRequestFilter]="Table", MyProd.[Tabular] Like -1, ([Forms]![My Prod]![PubFilter] Is Null)))
AND (iif([Forms]![My Prod]![SpecialRequestFilter]="Partial Pub", MyProd.[partpub] Like -1, ([Forms]![My Prod]![PubFilter] Is Null)))
AND (iif([Forms]![My Prod]![SpecialRequestFilter]="Has Notes", MyProd.[Notes] <> "", ([Forms]![My Prod]![PubFilter] Is Null)))
AND (IIf((([Forms]![My Prod]![SD]<>"") AND ([Forms]![My Prod]![ED]<>"")), MyProd.[statusdate] Between [Forms]![My Prod]![SD] AND [Forms]![My Prod]![ED], (MyProd.[StatusDate] Like "*" OR MyProd.[StatusDate] Is Null)))
```

I can't see how complex this is... Can you suggest a "simple" version of this? These are filters that when left blank the resulting query should return all. Thank you.

Comment: Try to [specify the parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641252/expression-is-either-incorrect-or-too-complex/51641940#51641940).

Comment: Try changing the Like -1 to = -1 in the Iif switches. using Like when you have a fixed comparison is probably not helping you.

To be honest with this many comparisons you would be better to build the query string dynamically based on what was selected. Review Allan Brownes search form here http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html